# How to force text to even/odd pages only

Tags: book-design

I'm trying to typeset a manuscript with some unusual formatting. It's a double-sided manuscript, with the main text going on the even pages only. The odd pages contain additional information that is relevant to the even page. When there is no such additional information, the odd page should be blank.

So, for example, given a six page document, an example layout would be:

1. Blank
2. Info about foo
3. Blank
4. Info about foo (continued)
5. Poem about Bar
6. Info about Bar

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this with LaTeX?

Comment: Can the material on the left-hand pages be assumed to span no more than one page? Similar question for the right-hand pages. Is there ever a chance that there will be something on a right-hand page *without* anything being placed on the left? Are you using a particular document class?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I can't assume that. Both odd and even sections can span multiple sections.

Yes, the right-hand page can be non-empty while the left-hand page is empty (not vice versa).

I'm not tied to a particular document class.

Comment: It's a really good idea -- in no small part because it saves potential answer providers from wasting their time on designing solutions that don't meet your needs -- to mention these important features up front.

Comment: If both left-hand and right-hand materials can span more than one page, I think that the [`flowfram` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) is a solution...

Answer (score 2):

The problem might just be that you're "skipping a page of output", which is easily circumvented using some strategic interjections of `\afterpage{\mbox{}\clearpage}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,afterpage}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\newcommand{\nextoddpage}{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}
\newcommand{\nextevenpage}{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\clearpage\else\cleardoublepage\fi}

\begin{document}

% Document layout
% ---------------
% 1 Blank
% 2 Info about foo
% 3 Blank
% 4 Info about foo (continued)
% 5 Poem about Bar
% 6 Info about Bar

\mbox{}% 1 Blank

\nextevenpage

\afterpage{\mbox{}\nextevenpage}% 3 Blank
\lipsum[1-3]% 2+4 Info about foo (continued) (Lorem ipsum...felis eu massa.)

\nextoddpage

\lipsum[49]% 5 Poem about Bar (Vivamus sodales...rhoncus eu, magna.)

\nextevenpage

\lipsum[50]% Info about Bar (Quisque facilisis...Suspendisse arcu.)

\end{document}
```

The use of [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) may not be necessary, depending on your implementation.