# specific odd (or even) page

Tags: fullpage

I need to insert a specific page (filled with lines for note taking) on each even (or odd) pages. I find some indications on the modification of headers or footer but nothing to force a specific contents on the page itself.

Thanks to everybody for help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you add a MWE, please?

Comment: I just have a full classical document. What I want is :
page 1 : doc text
page 2 : page with lines
page 3 : doc text
page 4 : page with lines
...
I know how to produce the 'page with lines' but I don't know how to force it on even pages.

Comment: See at the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218358/how-to-force-text-to-even-odd-pages-only. There is a similar question.

Comment: You're welcome Fred. If you add an minimal working example all users can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses an `\afterpage` loop to implement the insertion.  The only down side is that it always adds an extra page at the end.

I put the "specific page" into a `\savebox` for efficiency.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\newsavebox{\pagewithlines}
\newcommand{\numberlines}{10}

\savebox{\pagewithlines}{%
  \count1=\numberlines\relax
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\textheight/\count1 - \baselineskip\relax
  \parbox[c][\textheight][t]{\textwidth}{\null
    \loop\ifnum\count1>0
      \advance\count1 by -1
      \vskip\dimen0\hrulefill
    \repeat}}

% add notes to even pages
\newcommand{\addnotes}{\ifodd\value{page}\else\noindent\usebox\pagewithlines\fi
  \afterpage{\addnotes}}

\AtBeginDocument{\addnotes}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great ! You gave me a complete solution.
I thank you very very much !