# How do I tell a double page in hvfloat to start on even page?

Tags: floats, photobook

I'm using hvfloat package as I want to have some full spreads in a photo book.
Cannot find a way to have the spreads start on an even page. But they seem to start random based on the text amount around.

Thanks for helping

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=116mm, paperheight=186mm,
layoutsize={110mm, 180mm},
textheight=420pt,
textwidth=219pt,
inner=54pt,
    ]
    {geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\chapter{1}

\blindtext[2]

\hvFloat[doubleFULLPAGE,capPos=before]
{figure} {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=2\paperwidth,keepaspectratio=false]{example-image-a}}
{AThis is my first image. There is no text before}
{fig:doubleFULLPAGE1}

\blindtext[2]

\chapter{2}


\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=116mm, paperheight=186mm,
layoutsize={110mm, 180mm},
textheight=420pt,
textwidth=219pt,
inner=54pt,
    ]
    {geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\chapter{1}



\hvFloat[doubleFULLPAGE,capPos=before]
{figure} {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=2\paperwidth,keepaspectratio=false]{example-image-a}}
{AThis is my first image. There is no text before}
{fig:doubleFULLPAGE1}

\blindtext[2]

\chapter{2}

\blindtext[2]
   
\hvFloat[doubleFULLPAGE,capPos=before]
{figure} {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=2\paperwidth,keepaspectratio=false]{example-image-b}}
{This is my second image, after some text and with some text after}
{fig:doubleFULLPAGE2}

\blindtext[2]


\end{document}
   
\hvFloat[doubleFULLPAGE,capPos=before]
{figure} {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=2\paperwidth,keepaspectratio=false]{example-image-b}}
{This is my second image, after some text and with some text after}
{fig:doubleFULLPAGE2}

\blindtext[2]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350004/specific-odd-or-even-page

Comment: Somewhat but I would expect double page floats to ALWAYS start on even page and end on odd page, otherwise how can I have a spread? It does not make sense that I have to manually force them this way...

Comment: There are several possible values for starting a double-age float.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean. Which value should I specify that I'm not doing? Thanks

Comment: See second answer ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already wrote: This cannot work! A *floating* page needs some text which could
be moved by TeX *before* a floating object so that the float itself can start on an even page!
You do not have any text, the reason why *floating objects* are completely make
no sense. Use simple \includegraphics[trim=...,clip]{...} for left and right part
of your image:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
    
\newgeometry{margin=10pt}
\null\newpage% start on even page
\sbox\IBox{\includegraphics{tiger}}%
\includegraphics[trim=0 0 \dimexpr\wd\IBox-\textwidth{} 0,clip]{tiger}
\newpage
\includegraphics[trim=\textwidth{} 0 0 0,clip]{tiger}
\newpage
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That are floating objects and you need a lot of text if you use double fullpage *floats*:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=116mm, paperheight=186mm,
layoutsize={110mm, 180mm},
textheight=420pt,
textwidth=219pt,
inner=54pt,
]
{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{1}
    
    \Blindtext[4]
    
    \hvFloat[doubleFULLPAGE,capPos=before]
    {figure} {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=2\paperwidth,keepaspectratio=false]{example-image-a}}
    {This is my first image. There is no text before}
    {fig:doubleFULLPAGE1}
    
    \Blindtext[4]
    
    \chapter{2}
    
    \hvFloat[doubleFULLPAGE,capPos=before]
    {figure} {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=2\paperwidth,keepaspectratio=false]{example-image-b}}
    {This is my second image, after some text and with some text after}
    {fig:doubleFULLPAGE2}
    
    \blindtext[2]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. The double page works but the caption does not go to previous page when I compile your code -- with no changes, in my system... It gets print on odd page of the double spread on top of the image. How could that be?

Comment: Also: It does not ALWAYS work, even with large amount of texts. Try to put \blindtext[10] in ch 2

Comment: Looks like a problem with `\blindtext`. With `\Blindtext[10]`  it works.

Comment: Right. The problem is with using dummy text from blindtext. With regular text it works, if I input enough. If you correct the answer I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: BUT: The caption is still not printed after or before the double page... but ON the double page. Any thought on this? Thanks

Comment: That is only possible with wrong `capPos=...`  setting. Show your code in a small example

Comment: \hvFloat[doubleFULLPAGE,capPos=before]
    {figure} {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=2\paperwidth,keepaspectratio=false]{example-image-a}}
    {This is my first image. There is no text before}
    {fig:doubleFULLPAGE1}

Comment: The MWE is the originally posted... Even if I copy and paste your solution... I still get the caption ON the page... I also find it strange but cannot understand what I do wrong.